# ProseMirror: using "holes"/contentDOM when returning DOM nodes from `.toDOM`

Tags: javascript, dom, prose-mirror

In ProseMirror, the [`.toDOM`](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#model.NodeSpec.toDOM) method of a schema usually returns a nested array that describes how to render the node to DOM, similar to a "virtual dom" data structure. This data structure can also contain what ProseMirror calls a "hole", represented by `0`. This hole is where ProseMirror will insert the content of the node, such as text or other nodes.

But [`.toDOM` can also return a string or a DOM node](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#model.DOMOutputSpec), which are simply used as-is.

**Is it possible to define holes even when `toDOM` returns a DOM node?** Do I need to implement a custom [`DOMSerializer`](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#model.DOMSerializer), which appears to be responsible for taking the `.toDOM` return value and producing a `{dom, contentDom?}` object. If so, how would I use that?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to define holes even when toDOM returns a DOM node?

No. Defining a hole makes sense only when there are multiple children DOM elements inside the DOM representation of a given ProseMirror Node. Defining a hole tells PM where to insert the next child PM Node.

Consider the example:

```
imageAlt: {
  toDOM: () => ['div', ['h2', 'Alt'], ['div', 0]],
  content: 'inline*',
  defining: true,
  isolating: true
}
```

This means that `imageAlt` will render like this:

```
<div>
    <h2>Alt</h2>
    <div>Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Children PM Nodes would have been inserted under either `h2` or `div`; so we explicitly pointed h2 to contain the child PM Node.

But in the case where `toDom()` returns a [dom.Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) but not an array, that means there is only one option, hence there is no need to define a hole. A [dom.Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) is always 1 level deep and any child [ProseMirror Node](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#model.Node) will be the direct child.

Comment: The question is how to define a hole when `toDOM` returns a DOM node. The example given here returns an array from `toDOM`, not a DOM node. (I updated the question to make this a little clearer)

Comment: Ok. response updated accordingly. I hope now it is clear.